# Cluster recognition and identifying objects, trouble using SHOTColor, help?

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using VFH for object detection, now I need some colour information about the point cloud that I will use, I don't know how to use SHOTColor properly, could you guys give me a light?

I used the following tutorial from the pointclouds.org:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/vfh_recognition.php

And I tried to make a adapted version for the SHOTColor, using only the descriptor, here it is the reference:
http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/structpcl_1_1_s_h_o_t1344.html

Hence, how can I make a comparison of the colour information and make a tree using the FLANN to compare and identify the objects?

Specifically, the rf[9] vector of pcl::SHOT1344, any help would be much appreciated

I'm trying to do it with real time recognition using rviz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224681/cluster-recognition-and-identifying-objects,-trouble-using-shotcolor,-help?/) by [Nxzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/25604/nxzx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check [this](http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_tutorial_4:_3D_object_recognition_%28descriptors%29#SHOT). Application may be similar with `pcl::SHOT352` descriptor.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1